# Angular - Generating multiple new components dynamically using ComponentFactoryResolver and need to dynamically change values

Tags: angular, dynamically-generated, viewchild

So I am using the code below to create new instances of components using the ComponentFactoryResolver, below are the files #1 is the component I am dynamically spawning and #2 is the component I am spawning it from

** #1 dynamically-spawned-component.component.ts **

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dynamically-spawned-component',
  template: '
    <p> The number passed in is {{ myNumber }} , but this number will be updated dynamically as well ... </p>
  '
})

export class DynamicallySpawnedComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() myNumber : number;

  constructor() { }

}
```

** #2 parent.component.ts **

```
import { DynamicallySpawnedComponent } from '../dynamically-spawned-component.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  template: '
    <div #container></div>
    <button (click)="addComponent">Add another component</button>
  '
})

export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  // The view child to spawn these new components
  @ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;

  // The reference to the newly spawned component
  componentRef;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  addComponent() {

   // Create the resolver
   const componentFactory : ComponentFactory<DynamicallySpawnedComponent > = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(DynamicallySpawnedComponent );

   // Create a new instance of the dynamically spawned component
   this.componentRef = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory)

   // Assign a value to the myNumber variable inside of this newly created component
   this.componentRef.instance.myNumber = 5;

  }

}
```

So the above code works all fine and dandy but let's say for example I click add 3 times and add 3 of these newly generated components, how would I access these newly generated components and change the value of an instance on any of the 3 of the myNumber variable?

The expected html should look like this if I hit the addComponent button 3 times:

```
The number passed in is 5 , but this number will be updated dynamically as well
The number passed in is 5 , but this number will be updated dynamically as well
The number passed in is 5 , but this number will be updated dynamically as well
<!-- THIS IS A BUTTON --> Add another component
```

Answer (score 0):

In parent.component.ts
there is a (click) event, But you are not calling the function "addComponent()"
instead of `<button (click)="addComponent">` change it to `<button (click)="addComponent()">`